# Returning a value from a function CoffeeScript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the code:

```
  country: (origin) ->
    @geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder
    @geocoder.geocode(
        'latLng': origin,
        (results, status) => 
            if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
              return results[6]
            else alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    )
```

I am calling it in backbone.js as:

```
test = @country(origin)
console.log(test)
```

As a test I am using the console.log. However I am getting an:

```
undefined
```

response, as the country function is not returning anything. I know that results[6] has data in it, as I can do a conolse.log there and it returns.

How can I make the country function return result[6] when called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that API, *per se*, but it looks like it's asynchronous, which means you cannot get the function to return the value. Instead, you'll have to pass in a continuation function that deals with the result when it becomes available.

```
country: (origin, handleResult) ->
    @geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder
    @geocoder.geocode(
        'latLng': origin,
        (results, status) => 
            if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
              handleResult(results[6])
            else alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    )
```

To use this, simply craft a function that knows what to do with the result and pass it to the `country` function:

```
obj.country origin, (result) ->
    alert 'Got #{result} from Google'
```

Comment: do you need to define handleResult before? and if so what should it be?

Comment: @CharlieDavies: I've augmented my answer with a brief example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In CoffeeScript the last expression in the function is returned, as in Ruby.

Here, your returning the result of your `console.log`

```
typeof console.log("123")
> "undefined"
```

I've noticed some people avoid this by putting a single `@` as the last line, which would just return `this` instead and avoids some awkward syntax.

Comment: hmm it works outside of this problem though. and works inside the function itself. how would i structure the console.log call?